# Getting "Could not get unknown property 'com'..." after upgrading Gradle and Android Studio to the latest versions

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

So as described above, I get the following error:

**Could not get unknown property 'com' for object of type com.android.build.gradle.AppExtension**

The code that it has a problem with is the following bit.

```
project.tasks.withType(com.android.build.gradle.tasks.Dex) {
        additionalParameters = ['--core-library']
    }
```

Would appreciate any help as I am a bit lost with Gradle and what exactly to do here.